# Using Parse Cloud Code to remove object from an array

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

Presently I am using Cloud Code along with the `masterkey` to modify attributes of other users based on actions of current user. I have an attribute `requests_from`, and I have managed to add items to this array based on the following code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('requestUser', function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId, 
        requestsFrom = request.params.requestsFrom;

    var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
        user = new User({ objectId: userId });

    user.add('requests_from', requestsFrom); //Changed from set to add

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

I have used the above code to add `currentUser.objectId` to a target user's `requests_from` column.

However, my issue is now deleting items from `requests_from`. Once the current user has done an action, I would like to remove `currentUser.objectId` from `requests_from`. However, using `user.remove` or `user.delete` isn't working. I was wondering if there is another way to accomplish this via Cloud Code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer helps you if you haven't already solved it ! Basically, after researching and failing to find anything, it appears that the solution to this is to do the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('removeRequest', function(request,response){
  var userId = request.params.userId;

  var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
      user = new User({ objectId: userId });

  var currentUser = request.user;

  var relation = user.relation("request");
  relation.remove(currentUser);

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  user.save().then(function(user) {
    response.success(user);
  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error)
  });
});
```